# Mark an email as spam that contains javascript tags (advanced spam filter)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, javascript, spam-prevention

I was currently testing the setting of Office 365 anti-spam inbound policy. I am having issues with some settings. Here they are:

**JavaScript or VBScript in HTML
MarkAsSpamJavaScriptInHtml**

***Messages that use JavaScript or Visual Basic Script Edition in HTML are marked as high confidence spam.
These scripting languages are used in email messages to cause specific actions to automatically occur**.*

I tried to send an html attachment through Gmail that contains JavaScript tags to a recipient's Outlook. However, the email wasn't marked as spam. Could anyone let me know why the email wasn't marked as spam? Any testing procedure would really help.

Comment: The better question is why would it be? What are you basing your assumption off of that this should be marked as spam? Without some idea of what is not working right, the question is not answerable. Please [edit] the question and provide necessary details for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Why would email from what I assumed is a email server that is properly configured be considered spam by Google?  Have the recipients mark other email you have sent and those individual recipients inboxes will mark future email from the address as spam.

Comment: Did you also set the "High confidence spam message action?" And make sure that the sender's email address or domain is not in the recipients safe senders list, or in your spam whitelist? Or bypassed in any other way with transport rules? Did you check the email headers to investigate it any further? Perhaps check the 'X-Forefront-Antispam-Report-Untrusted' header. SCL should be 9 if the rule is working. You can use the "message header analyzer" to help. https://mha.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Another question to ask is are you sure the javascript even made it to the recipient? Perhaps the javascript was scrubbed out or deactivated in some way by gmail, or perhaps it's rendered inert in some other way. I don't think any modern email client or mail system will execute javascript in an email. I've never used the option you're referring to.

Comment: Yeah I checked that. SCL wasn't -1. SCL is 1 for the email which I sent

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I found that for JavaScript or VBScript in HTML, SCL of detected messages are set to 9. Agree with Appleoddity, it's suggested that you could check if the X-header of the message is the same as shown in the figure below. If not, it is normal to not be marked as spam.

Reference: [Mark as spam settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/advanced-spam-filtering-asf-options?view=o365-worldwide#mark-as-spam-settings).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, my question was how to test not how to validate.

Comment: If your email does not comply with this standard, the problem may be related to the JavaScript tags you added. It is recommended that you check and replace Java related content for testing.